# Html5 audio can't play again after it stopped

Tags: html, audio

I declare a audio file in my page:

```
var audio = new Audio('my.mp3');
```

then I use click event to play it:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    audio.currentTime = 0; // to make sure it play from the begain
    audio.play();    
})
```

It can play only at the first click time, after it ended, I click the document, it can not play again.How can I let it play again?

Answer (score 1):

I tested this in Chrome and an exception occurs due to the audio.currentTime statement.

This worked (also in IE9):

```
$(document).click(function () {
    audio.src = "my.mp3";
    audio.play(); 
})
```